# ReactJS component state dropdown not updating

Tags: reactjs

I have a reactjs custom dropdown component which contains a list of mobiles.

1. Three instances of components get rendered initially.
2. I want to remove the selected mobile from other dropdowns

For example, let's say that the master mobile list contains  Apple, Nokia, Samsung, and OnePlus.

If you select Nokia in first dropdown then in the second dropdown you should see the mobiles from the list but without Nokia.

- First Dropdown -- Nokia, Apple, Samsung, OnePlus (selected-->Nokia)
- Second Dropdown -- Apple, Samsung, OnePlus (selected-->Apple)
- Third Dropdown -- Samsung, OnePlus

Comment: Did you do a web search? You can't be the first with that kind of problem.

Comment: I try but didn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can either keep the options of your dropdown in state and maintain a different state for options of each dropdown

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it this way

1.Have a parent container that renders 3 drop-down children component.

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            child1: ['samsung', 'sony'],
            child2: ['samsung', 'sony'],
            child3: ['samsung', 'sony'],
        }
    }
    render() 
       return( 
          <div> // see below for handleSelect function
             <Dropdown onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)} selectables={this.state.child1} />
             <Dropdown onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)} selectables={this.state.child2} />
             <Dropdown onSelect={this.handleSelect.bind(this)} selectables={this.state.child3} />
          <div>
        )
 }
```

2.In parent container, create a function that will get triggered when a child's dropdown option is selected. e.g.)

```
// In parent container
handleSelect(object) {
    // Do logic here. 
    // e.g. if the first child selects an option by
    if (object.selectedChild === 'FIRST') 
        const selected = object.selected;
        // remove selected from an array
        this.setState({ ... update the second dropdown selectables });
}

// In child component. Call this when option is selected
handleSelect(value) {
    const obj = { selectedChild: 'FIRST' , selected: value };
    this.props.onSelect(obj); // call parent function
}
```

3.When a child calls

```
this.props.onSelect(obj)
```

It will update the state in parent accordingly, which will pass down updated props to the children when it re-renders

Then child will get re-rendered with updated selectable object.

Comment: I am able to updated the state but  change in state value doesnt reflecting on dropdown control

Comment: In child component, you can use componentDidUpdate to see if the props have changed. If the props from a parent is different than the previous pros meaning the drop down selectables have changed then you can try to re-render at the child component level. Please try it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you only with a state shape. Components handling should be your own work.

You can use a shared state for your dropdowns. Where you will to store an array of items and track selected item.

For example somewhere in a container:

```
state = {
  data: [
   {
    name: 'Nokia',
    selected: false,
   },
   {
    name: 'Apple',
    selected: false,
   },
   {
    name: 'OnePlus',
    selected: false,
   }
  ]
}
```

Inside your dropdown component simple filter this array with `.filter()` like this:

```
this.state.data.filter((item) => !item.selected)
```

Handle select logic and selected item for dropdown label should not be a problem.